# eloquent ORM controller or model

Tags: php, activerecord, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am writing a web application, and I am a self proclaimed disorganised developer, I write things quickly and worry about maintenance later. I am working with laravel at the moment, I have quite alot of database interaction, all the examples of eloquent seem to interacting with database object directly in the controller. Is this the best option, or is it more organised to wrap these eloquent methods in a function in the Model for that relevant query. e.g.

```
class HomeController extends \BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
         $user = User::find(1);
         return $user;
    }

}
```

would this be better served as,

```
class HomeController extends \BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
         $user = new User;
         $result = $user->getSingleUser(1); //Being a method in the User.php model
         return $result;
    }

}
```

I realise this is very very basic example, but for organisational purposes is it best to seperate the database and "business logic" away from the controller?

Answer (score 1):

> but for organisational purposes is it best to seperate the database
>   and "business logic" away from the controller?

Yes

> would this be better served as,

Yes - you should separate your logic into the correct areas, to make the code more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

That's why MVC pattern is for. Store your db requests deep inside, also you can separate your model layer from db layer if you wish. If you more decouple your application structure then more manageable is your code.

Comment: Actually "model layer" is [the whole thing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html). What you were referring to is usually (in non-framework literature) called "domain layer" or "domain model".

Comment: Feel free how you are calling this. Decoupling and separation is a right way in oop. Of course model in framework can be a whole thing, but can you call a class which does not represent business logic  a model ? ;-)

Comment: Call from where? "Model" is not a class.

Comment: sorry, i should say 'can you name it' rather than 'can you call', but can class represent a model ? (I didn't say that class is a model)

Comment: Only if you entire application is a "anonymous guestbook" .. or something on similar scale, which would be kinda a retarded use of MVC architectural pattern.

Comment: not necessarily, pragmatically small scale models do not need a class more than one to represent itself

Comment: There are **NOT** multiple "models" in an application. Model is **singular**. A layer, which is made up of different groups of classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57557/discussion-between-dariusz-g-and-teresko).